# Php repeating some items in a while loop when it is not supposed to

Tags: php, html

For some reason when I run the following code it seems to repeat some things, the effects of which can be observed at 123isme1.com.

```
<?php
echo "<big><h1>Recent Posts</h1></big>";
$dirint = 1;
$dir    = (string) $dirint;
a:
if (file_exists("/var/www/html/blogs/posts/$dir")) {
    $dirint++;
    $dir = (string) $dirint;
    goto a;
} else {
    $dirint--;
    $dir   = (string) $dirint;
    $count = 0;
    while ($dirint >= 0 || $count <= 5) { //The mentioned while loop
        $title = file_get_contents("/var/www/html/blogs/posts/$dir/title.txt");
        $prev  = file_get_contents("/var/www/html/blogs/posts/$dir/motd.php", NULL, NULL, 0, 500);
        $comp  = file_get_contents("/var/www/html/blogs/posts/$dir/motd.php");
        echo "<h2 style='text-align:left'><a style='text-align:left' href='http://123isme1.com/blogs/posts/$dir/'>$title</a></h2><br>";
        echo "<p style='text-align:left'>$prev";
        if (strlen($comp) > 500) {
            echo "...";
        }
        echo "<a style='text-align:right' href='http://123isme1.com/blogs/posts/$dir/'>Continue Reading...</a></p>"; //seems to repeat from here
        $count++;
        $dirint--;
        $dir = (string) $dirint; //to here
    }
}
?>
```

As you can see it is only repeating the things at the end. What would cause this, and how would I fix it? (I really hope it isn't something simple that I overlooked)

Comment: I was about to ask if `a:` was a mistake. Then I noticed the goto and realized why I didn't recognize it.

Comment: @MikeB Yeah, I need to clean it all up, but this needs to be fixed first...

Comment: I did a quick update of PHP5 and it still acts the same.

Comment: Well, as you can see, it's decreasing $dirint to -4. Thus, this is it: count <= 5, which is happening after $dirint reaches 0. Maybe using and (&&) rather than or (||) fix it.

Comment: @ADASein after changing the whole line to  `while($dirint>=1 && $count<=5){` it eliminated all problems. The `||` is an old copied piece of code. Thanks

Comment: Can I post the solution as an answer and you accept it then, so I can get my candy? lol (it's for real)

Comment: @ADASein Yes, I was waiting for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if($dirint>=1 && $count<=5)
```

Rather than this:

```
if($dirint>=0 || $count<=5)
```

Because it will return true while $count <= than 5 even if $dirint reaches 0.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a less convoluted version using the [SPL DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) class.

A word of caution though - [SPL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) may not be available on your server. If you don´t have SPL you can do something similar with [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

```
echo "<big><h1>Recent Posts</h1></big>";
$postsDir  ='/var/www/html/blogs/posts/';

if (file_exists($postsDir)){
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator($postsDir);
    $count = 0;

    // we use the DirectoryIterator to loop though the contents of $postsDir
    while ($dir->valid()) {

        // @todo add extra check if you want to filter directories
        if ($dir->isDir() && !$dir->isDot()) {

            $cwd =  $dir->getPathname();
            $url = $dir->getFilename();     

            // @todo You should check if these files exist first
            $title = file_get_contents($cwd.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."title.txt");
            $prev  = file_get_contents($cwd.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."motd.php", NULL, NULL, 0, 500);
            $comp  = file_get_contents($cwd.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."motd.php");
            echo "<h2 style='text-align:left'><a style='text-align:left' href='http://123isme1.com/blogs/posts/$fn/'>$title</a></h2><br>";
            echo "<p style='text-align:left'>$prev";
            $count++;
        }

        if ($count <= 5) {
            // Advance pointer to next file or directory
            $dir->next();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

PS. You don´t get any candy until you stop using GOTO.

Comment: I know, everyone hates goto, but I donno the easiest way to get rid of it :/

Comment: Use functions to encapsulate code. Use [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Recursion_in_computer_science) if you need to call the same function over and over - like looping through directories or nested arrays.

Comment: I still need to learn functions, I get them mixed up with other things from other languages so I always try to get away from them.